# why does (*callback)() work and not *callback() or *callback in c++

Tags: c++, callback, operator-precedence

I'm a beginner C++ student and I thought that to really learn pointers and references I should try to make a callback function, something I take for granted in JavaScript.

But, for the life of me, I don't know why these parentheses are so important in `(*callback)()` and I'd love it if someone could explain it to me.

Here's some code I wrote that worked somehow:

```
#include<cstdio>

void function_two()
{
    printf("then this runs!");
}

void function_one(void (*callback)() = nullptr)
{
    printf("this runs first");
    if(callback != nullptr)
    {
        (*callback)();
    }
}

int main()
{
    function_one(&function_two);
}
```

Comment: i only put the parentheses in after the IDE complained by the way, if youre wondering.

Comment: `calback();` should work as well. `*callback()` tries to `*` the result of `callback()`.

Comment: yes on the calling side, but id love to understand the parameter that im excepting, i actually wanted to write something like void *callback, but it wouldnt work.

Comment: `*callback()` equals `*(callback())` (google precedence of operators), but you want `(*callback)()`.

Comment: @Dems314 --  *i actually wanted to write something like void *callback, but it wouldnt work* -- A word of advice -- C++ isn't a language you should guess at what the syntax should be.

Comment: You might want to look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of function pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sadly being new at this, i tend to use the IDE to cheat a little, but hpefully with time il see mistakes before they even show up in the error list.

Comment: Well, the issue about guessing at the syntax is that perfectly valid syntax that looks right can easily lead to a program behaving totally unexpectedly.  Things like commas in the "wrong place" that are valid in the place where the programmer put them,  using `==` instead of `=` and vice-versa, etc.

Comment: @FredLarson thanks fred il take a look at that one, never heard of it til now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact you can just write

```
callback();
```

If you are using the unary dereference operator * then it has a lower priority relative to the postfix function call operator. So you have to write

```
(*callback)();
```

Otherwise such a call

```
*callback();
```

is considered by the compiler as dereferncing the result of the function call.

Bear in mind that you can even write something like the following

```
(******callback)();
```

because the resulting function designator is converted back to a function pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`*callback()` invokes `operator()` on `callback` then dereferences (`*`) the result of that function call.

`(*callback)()` dereferences `callback` and then invokes `operator()` on the result of that dereference.

Two very different things.

`*callback` just dereferences the pointer but does nothing with the result. Semantically valid but doesn't do anything in this context.

See also [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1):

> why does (*callback)() work and not *callback() or *callback in c++

`*callback()` does not work because the function returns `void`. A `void` expression cannot be an operand.

`*callback` "works" in the sense that it is a well-formed expression. It is however not a function call expression, so you haven't called any function by doing this.

`(*callback)()` works because the indirection through the function pointer results in a function reference, which you call by using the empty parameter list. `callback()` would also work because function pointers can be called directly, in which case the indirection through the pointer is implicit.